# Precautions for standalone executables from Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a GUI application in Racket that works well in DrRacket. Now I want to create a standalone executable for distribution. Are there any precautions that I need to take at this stage to make sure that a safe executable is created for use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no, you shouldn’t have to worry about cooperating with the distribution tool. For most code, Racket can statically determine what needs to be included in the distribution bundle, so you don’t have to do anything manually. One common exception to this rule, however, is *assets* or other non-module dependencies, such as images that are loaded at runtime.

To ensure assets are included in the distribution, use the [`racket/runtime-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Fruntime-path%29) library to bind paths in a way that cooperates with the distribution packaging tool. This has the helpful additional effect of making sure your asset paths are working directory independent, so relative paths will always be predictably resolved.

Additionally, modules required dynamically using things like [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29) can obviously not be statically determined, so use the [`define-runtime-module-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fruntime-path..rkt%29._define-runtime-module-path%29%29) form to mark modules that should be included in the distribution. You don’t need to worry about this most of the time, though, because forms like [`lazy-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lazy-require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Flazy-require..rkt%29._lazy-require%29%29) automatically defer to `define-runtime-module-path` for you.

Comment: I presume there are no concerns regarding memory management or garbage collection parameter optimization for standalones. Also, are there any restrictions on commercial use of software created using Racket?